# how to add icon button label and input together in single line in ionic2?

Tags: angular, input, ionic2

In fallowing code I have try to add 3 element together but it fails and button is not showing in output

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label fixed>Origin</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" value=""></ion-input>
    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button icon-only>
        <ion-icon name="locate"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label fixed>Target</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" value=""></ion-input>
    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button icon-only>
        <ion-icon name="locate"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-item>
<button ion-button full>Start</button>
</ion-content>
```

it shows each item separately or text with label together but the button is not showing at the end of text box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this is using ion-row,ion-col for arranging in the format you require.Check [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#grid)
Example:

```
 <ion-row>
    <ion-col width-80>
       <ion-item> <ion-label fixed>Origin</ion-label> <ion-input type="text" value=""></ion-input> </ion-item>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col> 
    <button ion-button icon-only> <ion-icon name="locate"></ion-icon> </button>
 </ion-col>  
</ion-row>
```

Comment: I already Had this Idea but personally it was not interesting I did it but changing buttons to labels and add "click"  to label.

Comment: ok..you could add your answer..if someone else is looking for the same problem